# \autoref is only producing a number. How do I make it include the Theorem/Proposition/Lemma?

Tags: hyperref

`\autoref` is only producing a number. How do I make it include the Theorem/Proposition/Lemma?

Currently I have:

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] 

\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}

\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\begin{thm}
\label{Main}

\end{thm}

The following Proposition will help prove \autoref{Main}.
```

Comment: `\Cref{Main}` from the `cleveref` package probably?

Comment: Does that mean I will have to change \usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}?

Comment: No, just add `\usepackage{cleveref}` **after** the `\usepackage{hyperref}`. Note: **after**!

Comment: @user82130 The same answer I posted below (which includes what Christian Hupfer suggested) had already been provided to your other question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/256672/3954. Why opening a new question)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Really. I did not check, but even worse: The O.P. did not check neither ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In case you have structures with shared counters, you need a little more work: the package `aliascnt` provides a method to generate a simulated second counter that allows the differentiation between those different structures sharing a counter. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\newaliascnt{lemma}{theo}
\newtheorem{lemma}[lemma]{Lemma}
\aliascntresetthe{lemma}
\providecommand*{\theoautorefname}{Theorem}
\providecommand*{\lemmaautorefname}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
\label{aaa}
test
\end{theo}
\begin{lemma}
\label{bbb}
test
\end{lemma}
\autoref{aaa}\autoref{bbb}

\end{document}
```

Pay special attention to the lines

```
\newaliascnt{lemma}{theo}
\newtheorem{lemma}[lemma]{Lemma}
\aliascntresetthe{lemma}
```

notice, in particular, that for the `lemma` structure, the optional argument has the alias counter defined in the line just above, not the counter for theorems.

[image]

Using [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) might be an easier option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theo]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
\label{aaa}
test
\end{theo}
\begin{lemma}
\label{bbb}
test
\end{lemma}
\Cref{aaa}\Cref{bbb}

\cref{aaa}\cref{bbb}

\end{document}
```

[image]